# Eve Online + Wine 1.6 (U 13.04): Offline mode

Tags: wine, games, connection

I've freshly installed EVE Online, build 590158.
After installation, when launched, the launcher says - "Offline mode", couldn't connect, etc. etc.

**What's wrong?**

This is the Wine console log:

```
$ env WINEPREFIX="/home/ondra/.wine" wine C:\\sw\\hry\\EveOnline\\eve.exe
fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"PnkBstrA" failed to start: 2
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:gameux:GameExplorerImpl_VerifyAccess (0x134c50, L"C:\\sw\\hry\\EveOnline\\eve.exe", 0x33fd88)
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
ondra@lenovo:~$ fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
06:07:41: Debug: src/helpers.cpp(140): 'CreateActCtx' failed with error 0x00000103 (no more data available.).
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x33d64c, overlapped 0x438a8d0): stub
fixme:winsock:WSALookupServiceBeginW (0x33d6ac 0x00000ff0 0x33d69c) Stub!
[0901/060741:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(111)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 8
fixme:toolhelp:CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Unimplemented: heap list snapshot
fixme:toolhelp:Heap32ListFirst : stub
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x703e29c, 0x703de9c, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x703e26c, 0x703de6c, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x703e27c, 0x703de7c, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x703e23c, 0x703de3c, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x703e27c, 0x703de7c, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x703e23c, 0x703de3c, 1024, 0x0): stub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is going on:**

At bootstrap the game tries to load the libraries, it cannot find them and then crashes or does nothing.

**Possible reason:**
You are missing some libraries (redistributables and/or common DLLs) that must be installed first.

**Proper installation steps:**

Before you start you might want to read first about [winetricks](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks)

From [WineHQ database page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25823) (*HOWTO - Eve Online install on Linux*):

You will need to install a number of required libraries with winetricks.

- "winetricks corefonts d3dx9_36 vcrun2005 vcrun2008 vcrun2010" if this does not work try:

  - wget http://winetricks.org/winetricks
  - chmod +x winetricks
  - "./winetricks corefonts d3dx9_36 vcrun2005 vcrun2008 vcrun2010"
- wine Eve_Oline_Installer*.exe

**Creating a new wine prefix**

If you need/want to use wine different instances of "windows" for Eve.  (Important if you have a lot of games with various installed dlls, and overrides that conflict.)  Creating a new prefix is simple create the directory and add the WINEPREFIX to all wine and winetricks commands.

- mkdir ~/wine_games
- add "WINEPREFIX=~/wine_games/wine-eve" to all wine and winetricks commands.

**Additional resources:**

This [guide](https://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Install_EVE_on_Linux_with_Wine) is from EVE's wiki

Comment: Thanks. Tried the `winetricks` installation, but that failed when running VC++ redist installer: http://pastebin.com/gCdJhqf9

Comment: Still the same after installation of the rest. Perhaps I need to set the native/builtin somehow? But I haven't find a list of which should be set to what.

Comment: I guess you mean `wine ...` and yes, same result - crashes.

Comment: I also tried to run the installer from MS web. Same, as one would expect.

Comment: No i mean **winetricks** please read the first link about winetricks i've posted in my answer...Here a related quote: *Once you've obtained winetricks you can run it simply by typing sh winetricks at the console. You can also use ./winetricks if you chmod +x winetricks first. If run without parameters, winetricks displays a GUI with a list of available packages. If you know the names of the package(s) you wish to install, you can append them to the winetricks command and it will immediately start the installation process. For example* `sh winetricks corefonts vcrun6`

Comment: Well then `winetricks vcredist_x86.exe` just says "Unknown arg vcredist_x86.exe".

Comment: This failing `vcredist_x86.exe` is part of the vcrun2010 package

Comment: Try to run `winetricks` without arguments to open the GUI and try to install the dependencies from there.

Answer (score 1):

Use Winetricks-->Install a game ->Eve Online
or download PlayOnLinux --> Install -->Eve Online.Than Eve Online will be installed automatically...

Comment: Thanks! Right, since 5 years ago, EVE started working out of the box.